# Aligning html input and submit

Tags: html, css, positioning

I am having a ridiculous problem where my input text field and submit buttons are not lining up and I really can't figure out an elegant solution of how to fix it. As you can see in the image below, the input text field (labeled "Enter Keywords" in the upper right") is 2px higher than the "Search" submit button:

[image: Input field is 2px above submit button]

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="search">
    <form action="#" method="POST" id="search_form">
        <div id="search_inputs">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Keywords" name="keywords" />
            <input class="button" type="submit" name="search" value="SEARCH" />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Here is the css code:

```
#search_form .button {
    background: black;
    color: white;
    padding: 3px 15px;
    border: none;
    font-size: 7pt;
    height: 18px;
}

#search_form input[name="keywords"] {
    width: 175px;
}

#search {
    margin-top: 7px;
    float: right;
}
```

I'm pretty sure setting the font-size to 7pt is messing it up, but I'm not sure why and I don't know how to deal with this because that's the font size of my other buttons in the area.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Adding `margin-top: 2px` to your keywords input does not fix it? (or -2px to the button)

Comment: No, I tried that and it seems to just shift everything up or down but keeps the uneven positioning between the input fields

Comment: Are you sure there isn't more CSS that might eb affecting this? I created a jsFiddle and it lines up fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

adding a `float: left;` to the `#search_form input[name="keywords"]` style align's their tops correctly, then adding some `margin-right` should get you good to go.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vQkTJ/)

The issue stems from the `float: right` on the search button.  The input box has a natural `display: inline-block` to it, which causes the slight drop.  Normally when you float right the fix to this is to move that element upwards in the DOM.  This won't work in this case.  By changing the input to a floated element you are also forcing it to be `display: inline`.

Though I'm not sure why you can't just add a `display: inline` to the element.

Comment: That worked but I don't understand what's going on? Is it probably interference from some other css like @j08691 mentioned above?

Comment: It's not interference because the fiddle shows the same behavior without any additional styles applied.